# How is the $l^p$ space separable?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I have been asked to prove that the $l^p$ space for $1\leq p<\infty$ is separable. A space is separable when we can find a dense **countable** subset of that space.

The argument given in my book is the following:

> Take a sequence $\{a_1,a_2,\dots\}$. There exists $n\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}{|a_{n+i}|^p}<\epsilon/2$. Now take the sequence $\{r_1,r_2,\dots,r_n,0,0,\dots\}$, where $r_1,r_2,\dots,r_n\in\Bbb{Q}$ and $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}{|a_{j}-r_j|^p}<\epsilon/2$. Then the set of all such sequences (consisting of rational numbers and $0$'s) is countable.

I wonder why such a set is countable. The $n\in\Bbb{N}$ for which $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}{|a_{n+i}|^p}<\epsilon/2$ does not have a definite upper bound. It can go on increasing. So the dense subset that we're talking about may actually be $\underbrace{\Bbb{Q}\times\Bbb{Q}\times\dots}_{\Bbb{Z}\text{ times}}$, which is uncountable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that these sequences are finite, so you have a  countable number of finite sequences.

Comment: For any $n\in\Bbb{N}$, I can prove the existence of a sequence in the dense subset which has terms in more than $n+1$ places. Does this not suggest that we are taking countably infinite products of $\Bbb{Q}$?

Comment: Yes, it does not suggest it. Think this way, for each $n$ you have a finite number of permutations, so you have a countable collection of finite sets.

Comment: Write your set as $\cup_{i=1}^n S_i$, where $S_i$ is the set of sequences with rational coordinates whose $j$th coordinates are zero for $j>i$. Your set then is a countable union of countable sets.

Comment: Note that the set you're talking about is the set  all sequences with rational coordinates, including e.g. $(1,1,\ldots)$. It's far larger than the set you want (the set of sequences with rational coordinates that are eventually zero).

Comment: @DavidMitra: you should consider posting your comment as an answer.

Comment: Why is $\sum |a_i -r_i|^p < \epsilon / 2?$

Comment: @KeesTil, it is a finite sum. You can take $r_i$ in a such way that this is true.

Answer (score 3):

It is true that the $n\in\mathbb{N}$ for which $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|a_{n+i}|^p<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ does not have a definite upper bound, and can "go on increasing". However, your inference that "the dense subset that we're talking about may actually be $\underbrace{\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\times\dots}_{\text{$\mathbb{Z}$ times}}$" is incorrect. $n$ may be arbitrarily large, but it is a natural number nonetheless — in particular, it remains a finite quantity.

To elucidate further, if $D$ denotes "the set of all such sequences (consisting of rational numbers and $0$'s)", *i.e.,* the set of sequences with finite support and rational entries, then we may write $D=\{(q_1,\dots,q_n,0,\dots)\mid n\in\mathbb{N},q_i\in\mathbb{Q},1\leq i\leq n\}$. Observe then that $D\leftrightarrow\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}(\prod_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{Q})$ - which certainly is countable, as the countable union of a finite product of countable sets.